# try: and exception: error

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

So i am working on this code below. It complied alright when my Reff.txt has more than one line. But it doesnt work when my Reff.txt file has one line. Why is that? I also wondering why my code doesn't run "try" portion of my code but it always run only "exception" part.

- so i have a reference file which has a list of ids (one id per line)
- I use the reference file(Reff.txt) as a reference to search through the database from the website and the database from the server within my network.
- The result i should get is there should be an output file and file with information of that id; for each reference id

However, this code doesn't do anything on my "try:" portion at all

```
import sys

import urllib2

from lxml import etree

import os

getReference = open('Reff.txt','r') #open the file that contains list of reference ids

global tID 

for tID in getReference:    

    tID = tID.strip()

    try:
        with open(''+tID.strip()+'.txt') as f: pass
        fileInput = open(''+tID+'.txt','r')
        readAA = fileInput.read()
        store_value = (readAA.partition('\n'))
        aaSequence = store_value[2].replace('\n', '') #concatenate lines
        makeList = list(aaSequence)#print makeList
        inRange = ''
        fileAddress = '/database/int/data/'+tID+'.txt'
        filename = open(fileAddress,'r')#name of the working file
        print fileAddress
        with open(fileAddress,'rb') as f:
            root = etree.parse(f)
            for lcn in root.xpath("/protein/match[@dbname='PFAM']/lcn"):#find dbname =PFAM

                start = int(lcn.get("start"))#if it is PFAM then look for start value
                end = int(lcn.get("end"))#if it is PFAM then also look for end value
                while start <= end:
                    inRange = makeList[start]
                    start += 1
                    print outputFile.write(inRange) 
                    outputFile.close()
                break
            break
        break

    except IOError as e:


        newURL ='http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/'+tID+'.fasta'
        print newURL
        response = urllib2.urlopen(''+newURL) #go to the website and grab the information 
        creatNew = open(''+uniprotID+'.txt','w')
        html = response.read() #read file
        creatNew.write(html) 
        creatNew.close()
```

Comment: What's going on with your with block? It immediately passes...

Comment: take it out of the try except block and see what error you are getting... at a guess the file doesnt exist

Comment: Why is there an unconditional `break` after every block?

Comment: Also, `filename = open(` is a bit mis-leading, since it's not the name, it's an object and you can just use `etree.parse('filename')`without opening a handle explicitly

Comment: It might help if you explain what you have, and what you'd like to achieve (perhaps in bullet points) - I'm struggling to follow the code and your intent here...

Comment: There's a lot of weirdness in this code... what are you trying to do here?  You have way too much wrapped in your try, breaks that don't make sense, and code that does nothing other than loop.

Comment: You're going to find this problem very difficult to debug because you have so much code in your `try` suite. I count no fewer than seven statements that could raise `IOError` (which has a variety of meanings) and there's no way to know which of these statements raised it any particular time.

Comment: @kindall what should i do instead? Is there a particular command i should use.

Comment: @JonClements I just added bullet points.. i am not sure if that make sense.. thanks for your help

Comment: @JoranBeasley what should i take off? I dont get what you mean by your comment. thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably break down your code more and put only stuff you actually want to check in `try` blocks.

Comment: Why are you using the `global` keyword here? There's only one scope in the whole code you posted. Also, why import `sys` and `os` if you're not using them?

Comment: **Never** put that much code in a try-except block. You should try only what you think might fail, typically one or two lines of code, and handle exceptions in that small block, handling only the types of exceptions you expect. Be *very* specific and explicit about what you're trying and what exceptions you're handling. If that means having multiple try-except blocks, so be it. You're obviously new to this stuff, but you'll soon learn how much pain a veiled error can cause.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you do Try/Except - if try fails, Except runs. Except is always running, because Try is always failing.

Most likely reason for this is that you have this - "print outputFile.write(inRange)", but you have not previously declared outputFile.

ETA: Also, it looks like you are only interested in testing to the first pass of the for loop? You break at that point. Your other breaks are extraneous in that case, because they will never be reached while that one is there.

Comment: I am trying to check if  there is "dbname =pfam". If not then i don't want to create an output file. But i am not sure what would be the best way to do this.

Comment: You have to declare the outputFile object at some point, before you use it. When you get inside the FOR loop, you already know that the dbname=pfram thing is true, right? So just put "outputFile = open(#whatever)" right there where you declare start and end, you know?